# slide downeffect the View problem android

Tags: android

How can i have slide downeffect? The effect will be similar with search function on google map of android. When we click the search option from option menu, the softkeyboard will slide up and the search bar will slide down automatically.

Anyone provide any hint or any tutorial about this, or proper keyword i can search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OverridePendingTransition() method in Activity class helps u.

u can get the transition animation from android.R.anim package...

Comment: Thx for reply. So ur idea is creating another activity which perform slide down effect using OverridePendingTransition() method overlay on top of the main activity. when main activity invoke or start this activity, the main activity will be running on the background but still visible. Am I right?

Comment: you have to use the second Activity as subactivity. check the example in APIDemos http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/CustomDialogActivity.html.  for this subActivity you can override the transitions.hope it helps.